# Program his own plugin - show if there is a update of this plugin

Tags: wordpress

I had program my own plugin.
Now I want to include a function which display a notice in the menu 'plugins' if I update my own plugin.

So user get a notice if an update is available.
Are there existing functions of wordpress which can I use?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: you don't need a function for this. try version controlling or upload your plguin to wordpress. when ever you make any changes wordpress will automatically show notification

Comment: The plugin doesn't come into the wordpress repository.

Comment: You should take a look on that: https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker